# how to assign list of values to a key using OrderedDict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi want to have a ordered dictionary with keys having list of values.

from below code i could able to get a dictionary with list of keys but ordered of insertion is missing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys=['blk','pri','ani']
vals1=['blocking','primary','anim']
vals2=['S1','S2','S3']
dic = defaultdict(list)

i=0

for key in keys:
    dic[key].append(vals1[i])
    dic[key].append(vals2[i])

    i += 1

print dic
```

i get the following result

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'pri': ['primary', 'S2'], 'ani': ['anim', 'S3'], 'blk': ['blocking', 'S1']})
```

here i lost insert order.

I know defaultdict object in Python are *unordered by definition*.

And i know we need to Use *OrderedDict* if you need the order in which values were inserted (it's available in Python 2.7 and 3.x)

So changed my code as below

from below code i could able to get what i need.

```
from collections import defaultdict,OrderedDict

keys=['blk','pri','ani']
vals1=['blocking','primary','anim']
vals2=['S1','S2','S3']
dic = OrderedDict(defaultdict(list))

i=0

for key in keys:
    dic[key].append(vals1[i])
    dic[key].append(vals2[i])

    i += 1

print dic
```

and now i get the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dict.py", line 18, in <module>
    dic[key].append(vals1[i])
KeyError: 'blk'
```

Can any one tell me how to get what i am trying.

Comment: As a side note, you almost never want to maintain an explicit loop counter like that. Just `for i, key in enumerate(keys):` instead. (Actually, in this case, you don't even need the loop counter in the first place. Just `for key, val1, val2 in zip(keys, vals1, vals2):` instead.)

Comment: Also, do you really need to preserve insertion order? Often, newcomers ask for this, but the right way to solve their actual problem doesn't actually need it. In fact, that's so common that there was serious resistance to adding `OrderedDict` to the standard library for fear it would encourage misuse. (IIRC, it was rejected in 2.4, 2.5, and 2.6 before finally being accepted in 3.0 and 2.7.)

Comment: @abarnert, yese i really need it.
I create  my own class for it and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want the "Ordered" **and** "default" behavior, I think I would create a custom dictionary class to handle everything for me:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class DefaultListOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self,k):
        self[k] = []
        return self[k]

keys=['blk','pri','ani']
vals1=['blocking','primary','anim']
vals2=['S1','S2','S3']
dic = DefaultListOrderedDict()
for i,key in enumerate(keys):
    dic[key].append(vals1[i])
    dic[key].append(vals2[i])

print dic
```

This will behave more like the `defaultdict` than the other solutions, but it will retain it's order, and it really isn't a whole lot of code :).  Finally, you could even override `__init__` to allow the user to pass any "factory" they wanted (rather than hard-coding `list`).  I'll leave that as an exercise for the interested reader.  Python is so cool.

Comment: Neat, didn't know about the `__missing__` special method. It's not mentioned in the list of [special method names](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customization), but only mentioned briefly in the docs for the [dict built-in type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). A big +1!

Comment: As python 2.6 dont have OrderedDict, i have created a class for it and used you DefaultListOrderedDict. and it solved my problem. Thx for the help

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao -- Just FYI, there's an activeState recipe for an ordered dict that works with python 2.4+ -- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693-ordered-dictionary-for-py24/

Comment: @mgilson -- i used that class only.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with wrapping `OrderedDict` around `defaultdict(list)` is that it's evaluated this way:

1. Create an empty instance of `defaultdict`.
2. Create an instance of `OrderedDict`, then initialize it with the contents of the `defaultdict` (currently empty), then throw away the old `defaultdict` because nothing references it any more.

This doesn't combine their behavior like you wanted.

The standard idiom I've seen is the `dict.setdefault` method.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

keys=['blk','pri','ani']
vals1=['blocking','primary','anim']
vals2=['S1','S2','S3']
dic = OrderedDict()

i=0

for key in keys:
    dic.setdefault(key, []).append(vals1[i])
    dic.setdefault(key, []).append(vals2[i])

    i += 1

print dic
```

Like defaultdict, this creates a value the first time you access it, although I gather it's a little less efficient.

I would use this approach though:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dic = OrderedDict(zip(keys, zip(vals1, vals2)))
print dic
```

Comment: Just got the same short solution))))

Comment: It is less efficient.  I have actually at one point created an `OrderedDefaultDict` by subclassing them both in the appropriate order -- But that seems like quite a fragile solution and I won't try to reproduce it here.

Comment: @mgilson, can you explain what the inefficiency is from? It's only due to unconditionally allocating an empty list each time, right?

Comment: Also note that your solution with `zip` isn't quite equivalent.  `zip` will give OP `tuples` instead of lists, so OP can't `.append` later.  You might need `zip(keys,map(list,zip(vals1,vals2)))`

Comment: @JameySharp -- Correct.  You create a list with `setdefault` even though you don't have to.  List creation is highly optimized though, so it's probably not a big deal here unless you're going to do it a whole bunch of times.

Comment: @mgilson, that's true, tuples != lists. It seemed unlikely to be an issue, to me, given the structure of the example, but I should have pointed it out. And thanks for the efficiency clarification on `setdefault`--I've been wondering why anyone was concerned about that.

Comment: @JameySharp -- It's really a concern when the "factory" that you pass to `defaultdict` takes a long time to compute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

keys=['blk','pri','ani']
vals1=['blocking','primary','anim']
vals2=['S1','S2','S3']
print OrderedDict(zip(keys, zip(vals1, vals2)))
```